# always having this "Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK"

Tags: android, sdk

i am getting this error

```
package com.example.test1;

import android.R;
       import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
}


}
```

made a new project. checked all the connections

Comment: change your minsdkversion into manifest.xml file

Comment: from where should i do it?

Comment: post your manifest.xml file. do it into manifest.xml file

Comment: Please search first. A simple Google search or search here would tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you want to run an app on a device which has a lower version of android than the minimum API level that you have specified.

First time you would come across specifying the target and minimum sdkVersions would be while creating your project:
Check- Figure 1. The New Android App Project wizard in Eclipse. in:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Minimum Required SDK is the lowest version of Android that your app supports. This becomes defined in your manifest at the initial setup/creation.

Now, in your manifest, you need to look at:

```
android:minSdkVersion
```

> An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the
>   application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from
>   installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the
>   value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this
>   attribute.

From app manifest -> uses sdk:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Read more about the manifest:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-project-manifest--mobile-20606